# bash script to rank files based on sorting the column

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to rank file based on the sign of the `log2FoldChange` multiplied by the inverse of the `pvalue`.

input file =

```
  Gene  baseMean    log2FoldChange  lfcSE   stat    pvalue  padj
ABCA13  5103.080785 2.543103478 0.438305758 5.802121998 6.55E-09    1.93E-07
ABCA3   18680.58642 -1.553638598    0.460873937 -3.371070638    0.000748767 0.003440638
ABCC1   25566.61312 1.835232419 0.297965004 6.15922137  7.31E-10    2.95E-08
ABCC2   200.351079  1.753257763 0.47254475  3.710247045 0.000207057 0.001190344
ABCC5   18904.8957  2.982575702 0.304484366 9.795497012 1.18E-22    7.21E-20
ABCC6   1071.195985 -1.858889875    0.388613973 -4.783384034    1.72E-06    2.16E-05
ABCC6P1 121.4678884 -2.319956403    0.367695124 -6.309456544    2.80E-10    1.26E-08
ABCC6P2 154.2820927 -2.402177208    0.393773373 -6.100405397    1.06E-09    4.06E-08
ABCC8   71.94941328 -1.651659127    0.494666609 -3.338933936    0.000841006 0.003782183
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
DGE=$1
RNK=`echo $DGE | sed 's/.txt/.rnk/'`
sed 1d $DGE \
| sort -k6g \
| awk '!arr[$1]++' \
| awk '{OFS="\t"}
{ if ($3>0) printf "%s\t%4.3e\n", $1, 1/$7 ;
else printf "%s\t%4.3e\n", $1, -1/$7 }' \
| sort -k2gr > $RNK
```

But im getting an empty file as output

Comment: The script seems to work. Shorten your command sequence and output to stdout to check each steps.

Comment: ./rank.sh  /path/to/the/input/file Gene_column log2foldchange_column  pvalue_column  returns empty file

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -walne 'print,next if 1 == $.;
             print $F[2] * $F[5], " $_" ' < file | sort -g
```

If you could describe what you mean by "sign", I could incorporate it into the script.

Comment: In the listed script, the OP changes also the sign depending on field 3.

Comment: Ah, I noticed the word "sign" in the question, but I didn't understand it. I didn't study the code, either, as it produces no output, anyway.

Comment: @choroba , i modified the input file. sign of log2FoldChange include both positive and negative values

Comment: @r.bot: OK, now what should the script do with the negative values?

Comment: @choroba, the script should take the sign of the fold change (negative or positive) and multiply by the inverse of pvalue

Comment: @r.bot: I don't understand. How can you multiply a sign?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR!=1{$0=$0" "$3*(1/$6)}1' file | sort -k8,8g
```

---

- `NR!=1` ignores the header line.
- `$0=$0" "$3*(1/$6)`: adds a 8th field with the desired result.
- `{...}1` the 1 is a positive condition, that `awk` prints the line.
- `sort -k8,8g` sort the 8th field.
- Additionally add another pipe with `... | awk '{$8=""}1'` to remove that field again, if desired.

---

**Edit**: In your code in the question, I see, that you want a positive result (if the value in `$3` is negative it should be `-1/$7`). Supporting this, here my changed command:

```
awk 'NR!=1{$0=$0" "sqrt(($3*(1/$6))^2)}1' file | sort -k8,8g
```

I made it a bit different; I squared, and then took the sqaure root.